# What markup language should I use for code included in comments to AUR packages website?

Tags: archlinux

I could not find documentation anywhere for what syntax/markup to use for formatting code in comments to [AUR packages](https://aur.archlinux.org/).

Answer (score 2):

The aurweb comments renderer can be seen at https://git.archlinux.org/aurweb.git/tree/aurweb/scripts/rendercomment.py?h=v4.6.0

It shows that the python-markdown library is used, with the fenced_code extension (triple backticks) enabled. Generally, most markdown should "just work".

It also includes a couple custom extensions to automatically linkify Arch Linux bug references or git commit hashes for the repository... there is nothing unusually out of the box here.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! I will try it out soon.